# how to translate entire iOS app into different language

Tags: ios, iphone

I am new to localization, I want to translate the application into different language.
Ex:I design storyboard in english, when I choose portugal language in application I want to load portuguese storyboard.

Comment: you need to go through localisation for that

Comment: Yes, study the excellent (well, mediocre) documentation.  You will likely have some questions when you're done, which are fine to ask here, but don't expect us to tell you stuff you should have read on your own.

Answer (score 1):

For languages and translating the application. You need to implement localization in your application. Have a look at the official documentation provided by Apple

[https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/‎](https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/)

and you can follow this detailed tutorial as well:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/localization-tutorial-for-ios

Comment: I want to change language button pressed in app,In this code we change the device settings language.

Answer (score 1):

There is library on GitHub https://github.com/marmelroy/Localize-Swift which support language switching in your app.

For translation itself i prefer to export XLIFF to Word (docx format), send Word document to translator on Fiverr a then import translations back from Word document to XLIFF file. There is new tool https://129bit.com/home/xliff-to-word-and-back/

Answer (score 0):

Praveen...

There is only one way you can change the language is using settings.. it not at all possible to change the language from button tap or any other event. You can have language change option in your setting screen where you write steps to change the language and user can follow them ....

This is the way I have implemented in lot of application ...